# "stream does not represent a PKCS12 key store" after storing with a new password on Android device

Tags: java, android, security, ssl, keystore

I wrote an Android application that uses a [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) to authenticate SSL connection.
But when I load the p12 file with the right key and stores it with a new one, the next time I try to load it with the new key I get this exception:

> java.io.IOException: stream does not represent a PKCS12 key store 
>   at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKPKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad (JDKPKCS12KeyStore.java:691)
>   at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:589)

What goes wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was (I'm shame to admit) storing a different `KeyStore` by mistake.
Making sure I work on the same `KeyStore` fixed the problem and now it works perfectly.